# Can't stop Vue JS (v2) from reusing components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue app that conditionally displays sets of the same component, I'd like to tie in to the created or mounted methods, but Vue keeps re-using earlier components and not triggering the methods. I've tried wrapping the components in keep-alive tags to no effect.

The code below shows what you would expect on the page: changing someVariable to 'test1' or 'test2' shows the relevant components, but the created/mounted methods only fire a maximum of 2 times (e.g. changing someVariable to 'test1' logs creation and mounting of 1 component with the label type1, then changing it to 'test2' only logs 1 more component with the label type3).

Currently using v2.1.10

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="someVariable === 'test1'">
        <keep-alive>
            <test-component data-type="type1"></test-component>
        </keep-alive>
    </div>

    <div v-if="someVariable === 'test2'">
        <keep-alive>
            <test-component data-type="type2"></test-component>
        </keep-alive>

        <keep-alive>
            <test-component data-type="type3"></test-component>
        </keep-alive>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS/Vue**

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
    props: ['data-type'],
    template: '<div><p>In the component: {{ dataType }}</p></div>',
    created: function () {
        console.log('component created: ', this.dataType);
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('component mounted: ', this.dataType);
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        someVariable: ""
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example removing `keep-alive` from the second if should do the trick https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/464/

An interesting thing is that vue seems to re-use the previously rendered component. So if you have one component in the first `if` when switching to the next `if` with 2 components it will re-use one component and create a new one for the second component from the block. When getting back to the first `if` block it will re-use one of the 2 already rendered components.

As mentioned above, a **watcher** is more suited for such cases, thus getting you rid of handling logic in places where you don't have full control. You can see this tip right here in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Answer (score 3):

You should use a watcher on your `someVariable` instead of trying to hook on `created` and `mounted` [hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Components are created, and mounted the first time they are visible (rendered). There are NO "shown" or "hidden" hooks.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers:

```
watch: {
  someVariable: function (newValue) {
    // test newValue and do what you have to do!
  }
}
```